# android - ads only on emulator and missing on real device

Tags: java, android

In my new app I want to use interstitial ads. The app can be restarted with increases a variable. When this variable `playcount` reached 10 and the game is over, an ad shall pop up and the variable should reset. It works on my emulator, but on a real device the ad doesn't pop up and the variable won't reset.

```
public class GameScreen extends Activity {
    public TextView tv; 
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private AdView mAdView;
    public int playcount;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        TextView playctv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        SharedPreferences prefsplay = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        playcount = prefsplay.getInt("play_number", 0);
        playctv.setText(String.valueOf(playcount));    
    }



    public void restart(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        playcount++;

        SharedPreferences prefsplay = this
                .getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefsplay.edit().putInt("play_number", playcount)
                .apply();

    }


    private void showInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }



    private void adView() {
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }



    public void gameover() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        imageButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if(playcount == 10) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();    
                    playcount = 0;

                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        });}
}
```

Comment: don't forget to update your `playcount` after you set it to 0

Comment: It's updated after restarting the activity, isn't it?

Comment: @quidproquo How do I have do update it otherwise?

Comment: I would suggest using `playcount > 10` in case an ad was not ready and `playcount` goes past 10, or else you will never hit 10 again and ads will never show. Update your `playcount` the same way you do it in `restart`, this is just in case the player quits before clicking `restart`, in which case he will be subjected to ads every single time since `0` is not stored back

Comment: Okay, but can you tell me why it doesn't work on a real device and keep counting there, as well?

Comment: I forget if they have a test mode, but try turning on test ads and see if that displays correctly

Comment: Test ads work. I also tried it first without the condition of 10 played games there the ads work as well. I just think it's too much so I tried to reduce it and with that it doesn't work